AWK compare index of an array
I have this command:
echo "29601 sc        20   0  608372  63680  46268 S  90.9  0.0   4168:30 vcs1" \
|awk '{time_=$(NF-1);  gsub(/:.*/, "", time_);  a[time_] = $0} END {for (i in a) { if(i < 50) {print i, "--------" ,a[i]}}}'

then its output is:
4168 -------- 29601 sc        20   0  608372  63680  46268 S  90.9  0.0   4168:30 vcs1

Do I wrong some where in that command. Why i=4168 is less than 50 .
I expect  that the command output will return when i put i > 50,  not with i < 50

Try if (i+0 < 50) to force the type of i to number instead of string.

the reason for the previous comment is that any index of an array is always a string, so for (i in a) sets i to string values

@RenaudPacalet  i try your suggest, my problem is resolved very thanks !

@jhnc It is a even more tricky than that. For instance, with GNU awk 5.2.1, the OP's version works as expected. Typing in awk is dynamic and depends on the context. But various awk have different rules to decide when a value shall be considered as a number or as a string. So, forcing the number type with i+0 or the string type with i "" is sometimes needed, sometimes not.

@RenaudPacalet by "as expected" I assume you mean "as the OP expected" rather than "as expected per the gawk and POSIX specs". That's a bug so I've reported it to the GNU awk maintainers, see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2024-04/msg00000.html.

@EdMorton Yes, I meant "as the OP expected".

Thanks to the gawk providers for the quick turnaround, the fix is now available at https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2024-04/txtui5CrhXeZ3.txt and will be pushed to git in the next few days and then into an upcoming gawk release.

gawk "works" because it's not compliant with its own spec :
$12 [vcs1] string
$11 [4168:30] string
$10 [0.0] strnum
$9 [90.9] strnum
$8 [S] string
$7 [46268] strnum
$6 [63680] strnum
$5 [608372] strnum
$4 [0] strnum
$3 [20] strnum
$2 [sc] string
$1 [29601] strnum

4168:30 string 1
4168 string string 29601 sc        20   0  608372  63680  46268 S  90.9  0.0   4168:30 vcs1
4168 string
4168 -------- 29601 sc        20   0  608372  63680  46268 S  90.9  0.0   4168:30 vcs1

Array index 4168 is of string type the whole time - when it came in as a field, after gsub(), and made into array index.
gawk's own manual clearly states this comparison should be string-compare :
        +----------------------------------------------
        |       STRING          NUMERIC         STRNUM
--------+----------------------------------------------
        |
STRING  |       string       [[ string ]]       string
        |
NUMERIC |    [[ string ]]       numeric         numeric
        |
STRNUM  |       string          numeric         numeric
--------+----------------------------------------------

[https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Variable-Typing.html][1]
@EdMorton

As noted in The GNU Awk User's Guide

array subscripts are always strings

which could give surprising effects when you ignore that detail. You might avoid that in your code by only storing value for which condition holds, that is
echo "29601 sc        20   0  608372  63680  46268 S  90.9  0.0   4168:30 vcs1" | awk '{time_=$(NF-1);  gsub(/:.*/, "", time_);  if(time_ < 50){a[time_] = $0}} END {for (i in a) {print i, "--------" ,a[i]}}'

gives output
4168 -------- 29601 sc        20   0  608372  63680  46268 S  90.9  0.0   4168:30 vcs1

Explanation: I moved if to first action and impinged it to time_, thus comparison is done before any array-related operation and thus mentioned quirk of implementation is outmanœuvred.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)
